# Route table for docker hub and vpc endpoints for private hosted instances: AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-ecs

I have a docker image which is just an Java application. The java application reads data from DynamoDB and S3 buckets and outputs something (its a test app). I have hosted the docker images onto public docker-hub repo.

In AWS, i have created private subnet which is hosting an EC2 via AWS ECS. Now to have security high; i am using VPC Endpoints for DynamoDB and S3 bucket operations for the containers.

And i have used NAT Gateway to allow EC2 to pull docker images from docker-hub.

**Problem:**

When i remove VPC Endpoint, the application is able to read DynamoDB and S3 via NAT. Which means the traffic is going through public network.

**Thoughts:**

1. Can not whitelist the Ip addresses of Dockerhub as it can change.
2. Since AWS ECS handles all the docker pull etc tasks, i do not have control to customize.
3. I do not want to use AWS container registry. I prefer dockerhub.
4. DynamoDB/S3 private addresses are not known

***Question:***

1. How to make sure that traffic for docker hub should only be allowed via NAT?
2. How to make sure that the DynamoDB and S3 access should be via Endpoints only?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF you want to restrict outbound traffic over your NAT (by DNS hostname) to DockerHub only you will need a third party solution that can allow or deny outbound traffic before it traverses the internet.

You would install this appliance in a separate subnet which has NAT Gateway access. Then in your existing subnet(s) for ECS you would update the route table to have the `0.0.0.0/0` route speak to this appliance (by specifying its ENI). If you check the [AWS marketplace](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace) there may be a solution already in place to fulfil the domain filter.

**Alternatively** you could automate a tool that is able scrape the whitelisted IP addresses for DockerHub, and then have it add these as allow all traffic rules with a NACL. This NACL would only be applied to the subnets that the NAT Gateway resides in.

Regarding your second question, from the VPC point of view by adding the prefix list of the S3 and DynamoDB endpoints to the route table it will forward any requests that hit these API endpoints through the private route.

At this time DynamoDB does not have the ability to prevent public routed interaction, however S3 does. By [adding a condition of the VPCE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies-vpc-endpoint.html) to its bucket policy you can deny any access that tries to interact outside of the listed VPC Endpoint. Be careful not to block yourself access from the console however, by blocking only the specific verbs that you don't want allowed.

Comment: Thanks. Market place solution i am not sure how good it is atleast for the production based solutions. 
Bucket policy for VPCE is a good solution. But in total for a production based, i do not see a simpler solution unless i choose to use AWS container registry then no need of NAT